# MediaPlayer doesn't resume video after activity restart

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, surfaceholder

I have a `MediaPlayer` object that uses a `SurfaceHolder` object as a surface. There is a button on top of the video that takes me out of the video to a website. When that happens, I pause the player with `player.pause()`. When I return from the website, I resume the player with `player.start()`. I know that the surface gets destroyed when the activity is not displayed anymore, and it gets recreated as soon as the activity is restarted. In my `surfaceCreated()`, I set the surface for the player again (since it no longer has a surface at that point), and then resume. However, the player simply restarts the video from the beginning.

I've tried commenting out the line that takes me to the website, just to see if pause/start works properly and resumes from last spot. It does. I'm not sure why this behaviour doesn't happen when I leave and re-enter the video activity though.

I also tried using the `player.seekTo()` call. There was no difference. In fact, when I disabled the button taking me to a site to just pausing the video, with the `seekTo()` call the video ALSO started from the beginning despite position being not 0.

The player object is the same all the way throughout.

Just because the surface is a new one on restart, it doesn't know or care of its contents, does it? The player should be managing that, right?

I'm out of ideas at this point. Can anyone please offer any tips?

UPDATE: So I threw together a quick app just to eliminate any other external factors. Here's the full code for the video class (other class is just an activity with a play button):

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener,
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private Button leaveVideoButton;
    private boolean isPaused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        leaveVideoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_web);
        leaveVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                pauseSteps();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        createPlayer();
        createSurface();
    }

    private void createSurface() {
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private void createPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    }

    private void pauseSteps() {
        if(player.isPlaying()) {
            player.pause();
            isPaused = true;
        }
    }

    private void playSteps() {
        if(isPaused) {
            isPaused = false;
            player.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
        player.reset();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        player.setDisplay(holder);

        if (!isPaused) {
            try {
//                player.setDataSource(path);
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.video);
                if (afd == null) return;
                player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                afd.close();

                player.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            playSteps();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: So I tried a different video and it resumed just fine from the same spot. This must be some encoding issue.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to improve your question.

Comment: OK, I added the code.